# Azure Front Door Rule Regex

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-front-door

I am trying to create a rule in Azure Front Door to match the first folder in the request path and then use that to set a request header to the back-end origin group.

https://myfd.azurefd.net/**config**/some1/some2/some3/test.html
https://myfd.azurefd.net/**identity**/some1/some2/some3/

I was able to do this in Application Gateway and get it to work as follows:

**App Gateway Config**

[image: AG Condition]

[image: AG Then]

However, I cannot get this to work in FD as per the following config:

**Azure Front Door Config**

[image: Azure FD Rule]

Answer (score 0):

Azure Front Door is offering 3 tiers of services; the feature and optimization "**Regular expression in the rules engine**" is **not available in the Classic tier**. It was the root of the problem here. Consider the **Standard** or **Premium** tiers. Please see the screenshot below.

Step1:
Front Door created with Premium tier
[image]

Step2:
Created a rule engine with Regular expression
[image]

[image]

hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, we are already using Premium tier. My question is not about the regular expression capability on the tier, but about how can I configure it to behave like how I have AG configured. I cannot find any docs on how to configure match expressions in Front Door.

Comment: Above replication is from premium front door service. Refer screenshot 2&3, there we have rulesets to configure regular expressions on applications similar like AG